# Can't archive working 6.0.1 Swift project in Xcode 6.1 / Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1

Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
While type-checking expression at [/Users/thedude/Documents/Repositories/MyProject/Data.swift:258:36 - line:258:56] RangeText="UILocalNotification()"

The error is referring to the following line of code.

```
var notification = UILocalNotification()
// also tried var notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
```

The problem only occurs when archiving (to submit to store). If I comment out that line of code the error will just appear in other random locations until I eventually have a project that is pretty useless.

This is another example of what appears after commenting out the previous code mentioned.

```
var someDate:NSDate = self.datePicker.date
```

And so on... The REALLY strange part is this project compiles and builds totally fine on the device. This only happens when building for **ARCHIVE**. I have set the **Swift Compiler Optimization Level** to **None** to see if that was the cause to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it is not the solution I would hope for I did discover if I set the **Swift Compiler Optimization Level** to **Fastest, Unchecked [-Ounchecked]** I am able to at least archive and submit my build.

I am assuming this is an Xcode 6.1 (release) specific issue and have filed a bug report.

Comment: +1 for filing a radar. I had a similar compiler optimization issue a couple years ago and the radar was what prompted the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your Deployment Target to 8.1 fixes this for me. I haven't tested Archiving but works for the Simulator.

Comment: The problem only occurs during archiving so this doesn't apply. Building to a device worked fine.

Comment: Building to a Device worked fine for me too, but i was having this exact issue with building to the Simulator. Hopefully it helps someone else :)

Comment: Also having the same problem on the simulator.  Updating Deployment Target to the latest available (8.2 now) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Xcode 6.1. Building and running the Swift project was no problem, archiving led to an error:

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
1.  While type-checking <my Swift class>
```

Changing the project's Deployment Target from `7.0` to `7.1` solved the problem, the app can now be archived.