# Swift 1.2 segmentation fault on compile of Release scheme

Tags: ios, swift

I've just upgraded to Swift 1.2 and when I attempt to compile the iOS application using the Release scheme I receive a "segmentation fault: 11".

```
0  swift                    0x00000001105a9a08 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40
1  swift                    0x00000001105a9ee4 SignalHandler(int) + 452
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff9a724f1a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff4fd6f6b0 _sigtramp + 3043272624
4  swift                    0x00000001100e837a (anonymous namespace)::DCE::markControllingTerminatorsLive(swift::SILBasicBlock*) + 346
5  swift                    0x00000001100e8109 (anonymous namespace)::DCE::markValueLive(swift::ValueBase*) + 201
6  swift                    0x00000001100e791f (anonymous namespace)::DCE::run() + 1983
7  swift                    0x000000011008f55e swift::SILPassManager::runFunctionPasses(llvm::ArrayRef<swift::SILFunctionTransform*>) + 1310
8  swift                    0x000000011008ffe9 swift::SILPassManager::runOneIteration() + 633
9  swift                    0x000000011008ea56 swift::runSILOptimizationPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 790
10 swift                    0x000000010fe92ee7 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*) + 4695
11 swift                    0x000000010fe91ae6 main + 1814
12 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff995665c9 start + 1
```

The application compiles and runs perfectly when I use the Dev/Debug scheme.

I have narrowed the compiler issue down to a single file and a couple lines of code.

```
let directPhoneType = PhoneNumber.Codes.Contacts["D"]
phoneTypes = phoneTypes.filter { $0 != directPhoneType }
```

I've tried changing the filtering code around (using "element in", etc), but each attempt causes the segmentation fault still. There is other filtering logic throughout our application that compiles fine.

If I remove the filtering code or change it to a loop that manually filters the phone types, the Application runs fine in the Release scheme.

**I've tried setting the optimization level to "Fastest, Unchecked" or "Fastest", the segmentation fault still occurs. If I set the optimization level to "None"; the project builds.**

This code worked fine before Swift 1.2 in both schemes.

Anyone have any insight into what is going on here?

**UPDATE:** It looks like Xcode 6.3.1 has fixed my seg fault issues.

Comment: You have replaced one beta by another beta

Comment: I found this and this worked for me. I'm not sure though what consequences it makes not to have the checks enabled http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508911/cant-archive-working-6-0-1-swift-project-in-xcode-6-1-segmentation-fault-11

Comment: Setting the optimization level to Fastest, Unchecked does not fix the problem for me. If I set the optimization level to None; the project builds.

Comment: 1. The compiler shouldn't crash. Since you apparently have a reduced test case, please [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) so Apple can fix this. 2. As a workaround, try explicitly declaring types on either `directPhoneType` or `$0`, maybe?

Comment: Ya, I tried the explicit typing, no luck. I've filed a bug and will use "None" optimization for now. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for reporting back! Note that there are also compilation bugs in 6.3.1, which are said to be fixed in 6.3.2 (GM seed released somewhat secretly today).

Comment: I think this regressed in Xcode 7.x :-(

Comment: Uh oh. We haven't upgraded yet. Hopefully its fixed by that time. :P

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same problem, without having code similar to yours. Turning off **whole module optimization** (which is off by default) solved the issue for me, meaning I'm still able to archive with *fastest* optimization settings.

Comment: I turned ON the whole module optimization (was off) and it worked on my side.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we have these sorts of issues *all* the time. The fault is not with you and they are frustratingly difficult to track down. Usually somewhat arbitrary code changes eventually solve things.

Various superstitions we have developed include: reducing use of `unowned` where possible, reducing use of `weak` where possible, being cautious of the `??` operator, being cautious of "too much" stuff in one line (like `max(min(x,y),z)`), switching `let` to `var`, etc.

In your code I might try switching your `let` to a `var`, or try removing the filter and doing an old school

```
var resultList = [MyType]()
for type in phoneTypes {
     if type != directPhoneType {
         resultList.append(type)
     }
}
```

or change `PhoneNumber.Codes.Contacts["D"]` to access that differently.

Good luck! Happy hunting.

Comment: I agree--this error can happen for any of the reasons stated by @wxs. From my experience though, this is the Swift compiler actually detecting a compile-time error, but for some reason, it can't produce a better error message. Allow me to add: check if any of your implicitly unwrapped optionals are nil, especially in areas where you chain them.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when switching to Swift 1.2 and not just for release scheme. While migrating, I had changed a recommended "as!" to "as?" thinking that it was what I wanted. That seems to have caused the problem; I went back and changed to "as!" and it worked.