# PHP7 + curl (SSL/TLS) gives 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am developing a webpage that uses the Dropbox SDK to do some things. Most of this happens through the CLI but one particular thing must be done in the browser. I stumbled across an interesting issue, though.

```
$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accountToken, 'xxx/' . VERSION);
$folderMetadata = $dbxClient->getMetadataWithChildren("/");
```

Running this code works just fine in CLI. Running it in the browser however gives me a 502. Being baffled I started up xdebug and traced where the problem appears. I found out, that Dropbox' curl-call was causing it so I wrote a small example script to see, if curl works at all. **It does not.**

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output;
```

Running this code in a browser gives a 502 instantly. If I remove https:// or make it a http:// (or run it in CLI) it works, though. The problem seems to be in PHP7 + curl + SSL. Adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` does NOT work.

What can I do to find out, why this happens and how I can solve it?

**System Infos:**

- OS X 10.11.2
- nginx 1.8.0, installed via homebrew
- PHP 7.0.3, installed via homebrew
- curl 7.43.0, installed via homebrew
- OpenSSL 1.0.2f, installed via homebrew

Comment: 502 generated by what? php5-fpm? nginx? or the string inside $output ?

Comment: My nginx. For me it looks like php-fpm crashes.

Comment: Update: I was able to test the example on my iMac now. Same result there: 502. It does work on all my three Linux servers, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sooo... after a LOT of investigation, I finally found a solution. Hopefully this will help future Googlers.

**Step 1: Investigate what is happening.**

Since I am using homebrew's php70-package, directories are a little different on OS X than Linux. I needed to find the php-fpm.conf. By examining the `homebrew.*.plist`-file created by homebrew I found it to be in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.conf`.

After that, I looked for the binary which, luckily, is noted down in the plist as well. For me it's in `/usr/local/opt/php70/sbin/php-fpm`.

I modified the config file to write a log file in `/var/log/php-fpm.log`:

```
log_level = notice
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm.log
```

I gave `/var/log/php-fpm.log` chmod 0777 (because I'm lazy), started up php-fpm again (`launchctl load -w /path/to/php-fpm.plist`) and tail'ed the new log file: `tail -f /var/log/php-fpm.log`

This is what I found (and what Googlers might look for):

```
WARNING: [pool www] child 28580 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 1.726773 seconds from start
```

So a segmentation fault is happening.

---

**Step 2: Fix SIGSEGV**

Using the newly found information I google'd what could be the reason for the segmentation fault. I couldn't find anything on the first few pages that helped but on one of the later pages, I found this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34951784/1486930

What it says is:

```
I experienced same problem early and fixed it with running php-fpm as root.
```

and

```
You just killed me. Running php-fpm as root just works well! Thanks!!
```

So this is what I did. I stopped php-fpm again and manually ran it as root:

```
sudo /usr/local/opt/php70/sbin/php-fpm --fpm-config /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.conf
```

And see, it works! I have no idea why that is the case but indeed running it as root "fixes" it.

I hope to have helped.

Comment: Runing php-fpm as root worked for me too, but I found that the problem was coming from `--with-imap` option. I uninstalled php and reinstalled it without imap and all works good. I don't need imap, but for those who need it, it's a problem. The issue is reported here https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/2390

Comment: Man! I've been trying to fix this since morning -- I want to buy you a beer!

Comment: 2021 and i solved this by running fpm as root (installed using macports): `sudo /opt/local/sbin/php-fpm74  --fpm-config /opt/local/etc/php74/php-fpm.conf`