# How to create a dictionary of weak references in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, weak-references

I need to store delegates which are views in a dictionary. Now I want to hold them as weak references, So if the user quits the screen my dictionary won't be the one preventing those views to cleanup.

I was trying to use the solution from:

[How do I declare an array of weak references in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127587/how-do-i-declare-an-array-of-weak-references-in-swift)

But for some reason as soon as I add the line of code where I try to get the real delegate from the weak object:

```
if let realDelegate = delegate.value {
    realDelegate.updateProgressBar(Int(progress * 100), aTaskIndentifier: downloadTask.taskIdentifier)
}
```

I get the following error in Xcode at compile time:

> Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Do you know what is the problem with this solution? Or maybe you could provide another solutions for this task?

Comment: Did you check this: 


  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156561/xcode-6-0-1-command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcoded

Comment: Yes, I did now... But my problem is not related to the solution there, They are saying to change the release Optimization Level, I get this problem in debug. moreover changing this settings does not do me any good.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSHashTable.weakObjectsHashTable()` instead of the build-in Swift dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Following works for me:

```
struct WeakReference<T: AnyObject> {
    weak var value: T?
}
@objc protocol P { // Note @objc, class or AnyObject does not work
    var i: Int { get }
}
class CP: P {
    var i: Int = 0
}
let cP = CP() // Strong reference to prevent collection
let weakPD: [Int : WeakReference<P>] = [0 : WeakReference(value: cP)]
print("PD: \(weakPD[0]!.value!.i)") // 0
```

But note I had to use @objc.