# xcode build error: swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Every time I tried to build the code getting the following error:

[error log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oO3l.png)

To create build always need to quit the xcode or clean the project for many times.
Looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: can you show snippet of your code? It looks some issue with your source code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR swiftc failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496582/error-swiftc-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by deleting derived data from Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Derived data

Then clean the project and run.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and its due to path references. You cannot move folders or files in or out of the Xcode project once it’s built.  . xcodeproj file should stay outside of the project folder.  If you're moving files around or copying folders, check `.xcodeproj` outside of the main project folder and verify that the folder and file structure is still intact.