# Command /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.1-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9, toolchain

I am trying to compile my code which contains some frameworks compiled with swift 3.1 which is not compatible with xcode 9. I installed toolchain package for swift 3.1 and tried to build the code.

But I am not able to compile this code. Getting an error:

> Command /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.1-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496582/error-swiftc-failed-with-exit-code-1-when-converting-to-latest-syntax

Comment: clear derived data and then clear trash and shut down than restart

Comment: @Manish_Nainwal I did this, but not working.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan Tried all solution from this , Code not working.. No Luck