# Build failed with error Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am using Xcode 8.2.1. I am also using CoreData in my project. 
When I try to generate a build or when I archive I am seeing the following error. Files mentioned in the error also changes at times.

**ERROR:**

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/anuragparashar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-drgjxhipxxqdrcatqfdgpayyxnud/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/app/BuildingRoofMapping+CoreDataClass.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/anuragparashar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-drgjxhipxxqdrcatqfdgpayyxnud/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/app/BuildingRoofMapping+CoreDataProperties.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/anuragparashar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-drgjxhipxxqdrcatqfdgpayyxnud/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/app/Region+CoreDataClass.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/anuragparashar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-drgjxhipxxqdrcatqfdgpayyxnud/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/app/Region+CoreDataProperties.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/anuragparashar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-drgjxhipxxqdrcatqfdgpayyxnud/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/app/StateRegionMapping+CoreDataProperties.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/anuragparashar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-drgjxhipxxqdrcatqfdgpayyxnud/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/app/WalkingDoors+CoreDataClass.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/anuragparashar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-drgjxhipxxqdrcatqfdgpayyxnud/Build/Intermediates/app.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/app/WalkingDoors+CoreDataProperties.swift'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

**Here is how my CoreData Entities are configured:**

[image]

**Things I have Tried:**

1. Check the location to see if files are actually missing, Files where present exactly at the same path.
2. I cleaned the build folder and removed derived data and build it again. Nothing helped.
3. Tried all the answers in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764691/xcode-8-0-command-applications-xcode-beta-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xco). Nothing Worked.
4. Accepted Answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156561/xcode-6-0-1-command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcoded) doesn't seem to work either.

I am not sure why this error is coming. Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**

If I completely remove CoreData from my code then it Archives Successfully.

**EDIT 2 :**

When I change CodeGen to Manual/None and add files manually as suggested by [@Anil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178089/build-failed-with-error-command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolc/43178511#43178511) . It builds successfully, But when I try to fetch the CoreData entity using :

```
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let buildingRoofMapping = BuildingRoofMapping(context:context)
```

It gives me run time error. 
Error :

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'BuildingRoofMapping' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'
```

**EDIT 3:**
   Sample Code [link](http://take.ms/u7IG9). Run it in simulator. It crashes in fetchBasicPrice() of ViewController.swift file

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Command+%2FApplications%2FXcode.app%2FContents%2FDeveloper%2FToolchains%2FXcodeDefault.xctoolchain%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fswiftc+failed+with+exit+code+1&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN720IN720&oq=Command+%2FApplications%2FXcode.app%2FContents%2FDeveloper%2FToolchains%2FXcodeDefault.xctoolchain%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fswiftc+failed+with+exit+code+1&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.443j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=swiftc+failed+with+exit+code+1+xcode+8.2&*

Comment: @iPatel thanks for the link. But before commenting please read what I have already tried and what you are suggesting me.

Comment: Set the module to `Current Product Module`.

Comment: @vadian setting it to Current Product Module doesn't work.

Comment: Is this the complete error? Because I wonder that `BuildingRegionMapping` is not mentioned in the error.

Comment: @shallowThought, Yes its complete error. I added ScreenShot for a sample entity. All of my entities are configured in the same manner. Also files mentioned in error keep on changing.

Comment: Means `BuildingRegionMapping` is also mentioned in the error "sometimes" ?

Comment: Maybe. I am not sure, because at times it lists 10 - 12 files so it is difficult to remember all the files. But I am sure that all the files have same configuration.

Comment: @shallowThought I don't think files have any connection with the this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below steps worked for me:

1. Change Module to Current Product Module and Codegen to Manual/None as suggested in [Anil's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178089/build-failed-with-error-command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolc/43178511#43178511), for ALL the entities.
2. Manually Create CoreData files. For every entity two files are created.

   - One will be EntityName+CoreData with below contents :

     ```
         import Foundation
         import CoreData

         public class EntityName: NSManagedObject {
         }
     ```
   - another will be named : EntityName+Properties

     ```
     import Foundation
     import CoreData

     extension BasicPrice {
          @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<BasicPrice> {
          return NSFetchRequest<BasicPrice>(entityName: "BasicPrice");}

        @NSManaged public var var1 : String?
        @NSManaged public var var2 : Int32
        @NSManaged public var var3 : Float
        @NSManaged public var var4 : Bool
      }
     ```

**NOTE:**
This kind of class/structure is not my developed, it is followed by CoreData internally when we select Class Definition from CodeGen.

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Today faced same issue but in my case I just do "Command+Shift+k"  2-3 time and problem was solve.

Answer (score 4):

I'll tell you what I have faced the same issue. In my case from Xcode 8 CoreData creates NSManagedObject class files in documents directory. I am sure you must have also created the same NSManagedObject files by your own.

You need to do following changes .xcdatamodel and regenerate a build. I have attached image below.

Make a change in **Module** and set it to **Current Product Module** and change the **Codegen** to **Manual/None.**

Let me know if you have more questions.

[image]

Comment: No, xcode auto generated files for me. But when I try to create files properties are missing in it, when I manually try and add the attributes then I get error where ever I fetch a request.

Comment: Yeah so as I said just set Codegen and Module as stated above. After that you will be having no problems

Comment: @Priyal : can you share your piece of code I mean project or demo? I want to see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139748/discussion-between-anil-kukdeja-and-priyal).

Comment: Sure. Lets Chat.

Answer (score 0):

First, If you are checking or running the code in simulator and on changes in coreData code you are getting crashed, then you need to delete the app from the simulator and then again install and run. By doing this, changes that are made in your code do not make crash or show error.

Comment: Code is not crashing on simulator. I am facing error while generating a build, If I simply run on simulator everything works perfectly.

Comment: After removing the build + Cleaning Build folder + removing derived data and then trying to build it again also results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing it as an answer because I am not allowed to comment yet.
From your comments I have assumed that you have cleaned the derived folder as well as deleted the app from simulator as well as from **device** while building on it.

Did you try setting **Build Active Architecture Only** flag to **No** in the Project settings tab? If not please do that as well.

While archiving, the app will be built for all targets. And thus some issue might surface which you would have missed by setting the flag to **Yes** during development.

Comment: It doesnt help. :(

Comment: I see. Try to select the whole project and not just a target while changing the flag. Also, Did you check that all of your coredata related files are linked to your target? You can check this by selecting a file and then look in the file inspector (Cmd + alt + 1).