# Xcode 8.3 Core Data "use of undeclared type" error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

After updating to Xcode 8.3 (and subsequently 8.3.2) my app continues to build, however code completion has completely broken.

From what I can tell, Xcode simply doesn't recognize my Core Data classes anymore, but for some reason, the build still completes successfully, and the app itself works as it did before. The consequence is that I have a ton of `use of undeclared type: [entity name]` errors, and code completion no longer works.

Here's what I've tried in order to fix.

- Delete the Core Data model and reconfigure it, from scratch.
- Clean build folder
- Manually delete the DerivedData folder
- Close/reopen xcode
- Cry a little, but only on the inside
- Change Codegen setting from `Class Definition` to `Category/Extension`, build, then reset, while also doing cleans and manual DerivedData folder deletes in between
- Validate the Target is set correctly for the model file
- Add `import CoreData` to literally every file that contains a reference to a model class
- Create dummy classes of the entities, which breaks the build and the original `undeclared` errors are replaced with `invalid redeclaration of [entity name]`.
- Update all entities `Module` setting to `Current Product Module`
- Clean project, clean build folder, delete derived data folder, restart xcode, build, in that order.

I'm convinced this is a bug with Xcode, but I'm hoping there's a way to resolve this without waiting for apple.

Comment: Are you saved your model changes? And what is the model name? I mean entity name

Comment: What version of Xcode / Swift were you upgrading from? Did you verify Target membership of the entity class files? Are you getting the errors in your main target or Test target or both?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning project, build folder, and Derived Data, without building in between? If not, then try doing all three in succession and restart Xcode, then build.

Comment: Can you add image of your error. Also check this if it helps :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43178089/build-failed-with-error-command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolc/43199965#43199965

Comment: @MikeTaverne was going from 8.2.1 to 8.3 (when the problem started) then 8.3 to 8.3.2. How would I verify the membership of the class files? I can verify the membership of of the model, but the model manages those class files. The only files I have are extensions of the classes.

Comment: Do you have class files representing your entities? If so, you can select file, then go to Identity inspector and verify it is a member of your target(s).

Comment: @MikeTaverne negative. I'm allowing the model to create the classes, not manually creating the class files. But I'm about to try manually creating them just for kicks.

Comment: Also see @Priyal's link above.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Priyal's link suggests to manually create the class files, which I would like to avoid doing, but if this is the only way to solve the problem...

Comment: @Priyal suggests selecting each entity in the data model, and setting its Module attribute to "Current Product Module". I believe this is done in Identity inspector. This is a good suggestion.

Comment: @MikeTaverne already tried that separately from creating the class files. didn't work.

Comment: Bummer. I feel your pain. Have you tried cleaning project, cleaning build folder, and Derived Data, without building in between? Then restart Xcode and build.

Comment: @MikeTaverne yep, I'll add that to the list

Comment: Youve probably seen this already but just in case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437891/use-of-undeclared-type-in-swift-even-though-type-is-internal-and-exists-in-s

Comment: @MikeTaverne yeah I had already gone through and validate every. single. file. in compile sources and verified they're the same between all targets.

Answer (score 1):

Operating solution for this problem is to set all the entities' `Codegen` option to `Manual/None` and manually create/maintain the classes, which sucks. What I did to make this easier is to build, go to the DerivedData folder and find the classes that xcode automatically creates, then just add those files to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I have also tried everything to get rid of it, but the error still remained. So I deleted Xcode, all logs and all user data in the app and reinstalled it. Now everything is working perfectly again. It is not optimal, but it is so nice to have a functioning Xcode again.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a Core Data-related issue—I get the same problem with a brand-new 8.3 Swift application (i.e., not migrated from Xcode 8.2 or before), where the only frameworks that I am using are UIKit and AVFoundation.

Interestingly, Xcode chokes on the first line of AppDelegate:

```
private var appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

This line give the undeclared type error. However, the application builds and runs just fine, so there is really no problem here.

Comment: It's not an issue with CoreData but is related to it. This answer doesn't actually solve any problem. If there are errors in the editor, but it builds, and code completion no longer works, that is a problem.