# Xcode error: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode

I imported a new code into Xcode and I am getting this error:

> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1.

How do you fix it?

Comment: About 60 duplicate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22swiftc%22+%22failed+with+exit+code+1%22+is%3Aq+created%3A..2018-02

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Xcode 6.0.1 Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156561/xcode-6-0-1-command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcoded)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Xcode 8.0 Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764691/xcode-8-0-command-applications-xcode-beta-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xco)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [ERROR swiftc failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496582/error-swiftc-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [swift failed with exit code 1 while compiling in Xcode - possibly related to Bridging-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889723/swift-failed-with-exit-code-1-while-compiling-in-xcode-possibly-related-to-bri)

Answer (score -1):

Try **<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>**. This cleans your derived data and might fix the issue.

As far as I know there can be multiple reasons why a compiler fails. Although **<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>** will help most of the time. If this fails, then click on the error message and try to debug it.

For example in the image below, if you read the message, we get to know that, there has been a name duplication. Fixing the name duplication will fix the [image]