# How read Header in Classes folder for using in my own cocoapods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, header, cocoapods

I made class Say for using in Cocoapods and that class needs Header like this:
[image]

And my header.h:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
```

But Say class not read Header.h
How to fix this and add it to Objective-C Bridging header ?

Comment: Just: `@import SayHello5;`

Comment: Import where? @Cy-4AH

Comment: Import where you need it.

Comment: :)))Header not found @Cy-4AH

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get why you need .h-files in swift?

Comment: My class that i added to Classes folder needs CommonCrypto for runs without bug. I know how to add Header in regular project but i don't know how to add CommonCrypto to my class in Deployment Pods/......... @Cy-4AH

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144915/discussion-between-reza-khalafi-and-cy-4ah).

Answer (score 0):

Please add a Bridging Header Class in your project using  naming like this

> <#YourProjectName>-Bridging-Header.h

Than inside this import all the framework Header file classes you need in your project file.

Comment: Get this error: 
<unknown>:0: error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Comment: i think you should check the version of Swift in that framework . If that is not 3.1 than you should use find one key in i.e "Use legacy swift Language version " and mark it "true". I hope this will work or you should follow this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156561/xcode-6-0-1-command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-toolchains-xcoded)